# Need to be automated current execution flow

Tags: java, spring-mvc, architecture

I am having 3.5 years of experience in java/j2ee.

I have some requirement like.In my project current flow is like user first upload a csv file(Customer details) in portal.After that admin will assign it to particular user.then user download the file and change the status field there.and then again send back to manager.But my task is to make it automated.There will not be any checker maker, and file upolad reading the file and change the status all this step need to be automated.Can anybody please suggest me some idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is a simple code change request not a automation task. But if you want to automate this in UI level, you can use Selenium. But if you want automate the process in back ground level, then you can use shell script or python or etc....

Answer (score 0):

If this is Web base application, You can automate it using Selenium.

Comment: I need to remove current flow and need to develop new work flow.I need to change existing  whole java code

Comment: You can easily do it with Selenium Web Driver,

Comment: You didn't get my point actually i want to remove those option like download ,upload,internally all will happen.need to develop new functionality. :D